# connection between android system with php mysql but i get error

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

i have login activity  that need connection between android and php mysql with using the jsn to get back the response from php and using asynctask to do the connection in background but the ystem display in the logcat that the response is null.

## logCat

```
02-10 10:20:04.053: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1797): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
02-10 10:20:11.717: W/EGL_genymotion(1797): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
02-10 10:20:21.840: W/INbUFFERED Reader(1797): before  the buffered reader beguin
02-10 10:20:21.844: W/INbUFFERED Reader(1797): the JsonObject is {"message":"No User found","success":0}
02-10 10:20:21.844: W/INbUFFERED Reader(1797): before  the Parsing beguin
02-10 10:20:21.844: W/INbUFFERED  2 Reader(1797): the JsonObject is{"message":"No User found","success":0}
02-10 10:20:21.860: W/EGL_genymotion(1797): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

i think that the problem is in the php file but i do not know where  and i did not find it.

if anyone can help me i will appreciate that.

## this is the table in mysql (this is a test)

```
-- Table structure for table `members`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `members` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `members`
--


INSERT INTO `members` (`id`, `user_name`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'cptjs', 'cpt'),
(2, 'lt_p_g', 'lt123');
```

## db_config.php

```
<?php

$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="fil";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost)
or
trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

?>
```

## check.php

```
<?php

require_once('db_config.php'); 


// array for JSON response
$response = array();




  if(isset($_GET['pid'])){


     $pid = $_GET['pid'];   



     $query_search = "select * from members where id = '".$pid."'";  

     $query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

   if (mysql_num_rows($query_exec)>0) 
   {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($query_exec);

        $person = array();
        $response["pid"]=$result["id"];
        $person["username"]=$result["user_name"];
        $person["password"]=$result["password"];



   error_log(print_r($response, true));
   // success
        $response["success"] = 1;

   // user node
        $response["person"] = array();

        array_push($response["person"], $person);

   // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    }
    else
    {




    error_log(print_r($response, true));


   // no user found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No User found";


  error_log(print_r($response, true));

   // echo no users JSON
           echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else 
{
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) are missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}    
?>
```

## JSONParser.java

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method

            /*
             * if (method == "POST") { // request method is POST //
             * DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); HttpPost
             * httpPost = new HttpPost(url); httpPost.setEntity(new
             * UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
             * 
             * HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
             * HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity(); is =
             * httpEntity.getContent();
             * 
             * }
             */

            if (method == "GET") {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {

            Log.w("INbUFFERED Reader", "before  the buffered reader beguin");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);

            }
            is.close();

            json = sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length() - 1);
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            Log.w("INbUFFERED Reader", "the JsonObject is " + jObj);
            Log.w("INbUFFERED Reader", "before  the Parsing beguin");
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);

            Log.w("INbUFFERED  2 Reader", "the JsonObject is" + jObj);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

## AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.java

```
package pack.coderzheaven;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et, pass;
    String Username, Password;
    TextView tv;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single person url
    // ******************************************************************
    // the localhost in the google android emulator = 10.0.2.2
    // the localhost in the genymotion emulator = 10.0.3.2
    // ******************************************************************
    private static final String url_check_login = "http://10.0.3.2/check.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PERSON = "person";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_pass = "password";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Getting complete person details in background thread
                new CheckLogin().execute();

            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete person details
     * */
    class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        JSONArray productObj;

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading person details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting person details in background thread
         * */

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting person details by making HTTP request
                // Note that person details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_login,
                        "GET", params);

//Log.e("JsonObject", json.toString());
// check your log for json response
// Log.d("Single person Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully received person details
                    productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PERSON); // JSON Array

                }

                else {
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            if (productObj != null) {
                try {
                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                    et.setText(person.getString(TAG_NAME));
                    pass.setText(person.getString(TAG_pass));

                    Log.e("success in login", "SUCCESS IN LOGIN");

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `pid` is Empty so assign value before passing to `BasicNameValuePair`

Comment: how to assign value to the pid knowing that  i need to get the id from the database then will check if login success ... i did not understand your comment

Comment: comment is very simple. i mean what you are passing here `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));` ?? becuase you are not assigning value to `pid` so in PHP  you will recive `pid=null` or empty string. then database query is `select * from members where id = ' ' `. that's why you are getting `No User found`

Comment: so where i must change the code you mean i must create pid = 0 as an example ??

Comment: ok,make primary in table which user know like `username` then pass username and pass in request instead of `pid` and in sql f selection using AND i.e, `select * from members where user_name = 'cptjs' AND password='cpt'` . i hope you understand what im saying.

Answer (score 0):

In your MySQL table, change id to pid. Now, in your xml file, create a textview and give it an id of pid and a visibility of "gone".  In the code

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Getting complete person details in background thread
                new CheckLogin().execute();

            }
```

after  public void onClick(View v) {,put in String pid = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.pid).getText().toString();......hope this helps